# How to Use Loop for Nested Dictionaries to Compare Previous Values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working on a trying to create my own code for stock trade.
With a Nested Dictionary

```
Dict = { 
  "2020-03-27": {"Price": "483.4200", "Volume": "14377408"},
  "2020-03-30": {"Price": "543.3600", "Volume": "14377408"},
  "2020-04-01": {"Price": "613.1600", "Volume": "14377408"},
  "2020-04-02": {"Price": "631.0900", "Volume": "14377408"}
}
```

With the above dictionary, I was trying to find a way how I can compare each previous
"Price" value, and go on from there.
Something I have in mind is like the one below.
Although I know Dict[i-1] is stupid because i is a string, "2020-03-27" and etc,
and not going to work, but is there a way how something like this can be done??

```
for i in Dict:
   if (float(Dict[i]["Price"])) > (float(Dict[i-1]["Price"]))): 
       print("Higher price than previous day")
```

The best I can come up to get around this with my limited knowledge in python is as below.
But, I don`t like the fact that I have to make a temporary variable to compare with the price value running in loop...

```
previous = 9999999999
for i in Dict:
if (float(previous) < float(Dict[i]["Price"])): 
    print("Higher price than previous day")
previous = float(Dict[i]["Price"])
```

Comment: Thank you Trenton. 
I never tried Panda but you gave me more reason to try it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's pretty what you are looking for.
Here's my piece of code and it is intuitive. Here we may make use of `Dict.keys()` and we may later transform it as a `list` storing all the keys that can be referenced using any `int` variable like you tried to use. Later we put a `try except` block to catch any `IndexError` that will occur once when we reach at the and of the `Dict`

```
Dict = { 
  "2020-03-27": {"Price": "483.4200", "Volume": "14377408"},
  "2020-03-30": {"Price": "543.3600", "Volume": "14377408"},
  "2020-04-01": {"Price": "613.1600", "Volume": "14377408"},
  "2020-04-02": {"Price": "631.0900", "Volume": "14377408"}
}


for i in range(len(Dict)):
  prev_key = list(Dict.keys())[i]

  try:
    next_key = list(Dict.keys())[i+1]

    if float(Dict[next_key]['Price']) > float(Dict[prev_key]['Price']):
      print("Higher Price than Previousday")

  except:
    print("Reached at The end !")
```

Answer (score 2):

## Use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)

- Pandas was designed for this type of analysis

  - Many of the pandas methods are vectorized, which means they're considerably faster than iterating.
- There are too many methods to go over in a single question
- However, the data is now in a format where all the value are easily accessible

  - See [Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)
- Use [`pandas.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) to compare a value to a previous value

```py
import pandas as pd

# the data
my_dict = {"2020-03-27": {"Price": "483.4200", "Volume": "14377408"},
           "2020-03-30": {"Price": "543.3600", "Volume": "14377408"},
           "2020-04-01": {"Price": "613.1600", "Volume": "14377408"},
           "2020-04-02": {"Price": "631.0900", "Volume": "14377408"}}

# read it into pandas
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='index')

# display(df)
               Price    Volume
2020-03-27  483.4200  14377408
2020-03-30  543.3600  14377408
2020-04-01  613.1600  14377408
2020-04-02  631.0900  14377408

# check if a value is greater than the previous value
df['greater_previous_value'] = df.Price > df.Price.shift()

# display(df)
               Price    Volume  greater_previous_value
2020-03-27  483.4200  14377408                   False
2020-03-30  543.3600  14377408                    True
2020-04-01  613.1600  14377408                    True
2020-04-02  631.0900  14377408                    True
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way,

```
dict_ = {
  "2020-03-27": {"Price": "483.4200", "Volume": "14377408"},
  "2020-03-30": {"Price": "543.3600", "Volume": "14377408"},
  "2020-04-01": {"Price": "613.1600", "Volume": "14377408"},
  "2020-04-02": {"Price": "631.0900", "Volume": "14377408"}
}

prev_date = ""

for k,v in enumerate(dict_):
    # 0, 2020-03-27
    # 1, 2020-03-30
    # ...
    if k == 0:
        prev_date = v
        continue
    
    # dict_['2020-03-30']['Price'] > dict['2020-03-27']["Price"]
    # dict_['2020-03-01']['Price'] > dict['2020-03-30']["Price"]
    # ...
    if dict_[v]['Price'] > dict_[prev_date]['Price']:
        print("Higher price than previous day")

    # update previous date.
    prev_date = v
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas (as Trenton suggested) is a good idea.

But if you don't want to use pandas,
you can use python's OrderedDict to maintain the order of keys (by the order they were inserted into the dictionary):
https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Example code:

```
import collections

Dict  = collections.OrderedDict()

Dict["2020-03-27"] = {"Price": "483.4200", "Volume": "14377408"}
Dict["2020-03-30"] = {"Price": "543.3600", "Volume": "14377408"}
Dict["2020-04-01"] = {"Price": "613.1600", "Volume": "14377408"}
Dict["2020-04-02"] = {"Price": "631.0900", "Volume": "14377408"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can offer for you. Sorry for not commenting much on my code. Hope you will understand.

```
my_dict = {
    "2020-03-27": {"Price": "483.4200", "Volume": "14377408"},
    "2020-03-30": {"Price": "543.3600", "Volume": "14377408"},
    "2020-04-01": {"Price": "613.1600", "Volume": "14377408"},
    "2020-04-02": {"Price": "631.0900", "Volume": "14377408"}
}

sorted_lst = sorted(my_dict)  # sort the dates

prev_date = sorted_lst[0]
prev_price = my_dict[prev_date]["Price"]

i = 1  # start at index one since we have fetched values for index 0
while i < len(sorted_lst):
    result_string = "Prev Date: \t{}\n".format(prev_date)
    result_string += "Current Date: \t{}\n".format(sorted_lst[i])
    result_string += "Prev Price: \t{}\n".format(prev_price)
    result_string += "Current Price \t{}\n".format(my_dict[sorted_lst[i]]["Price"])
    comparison = ""
    if my_dict[sorted_lst[i]]["Price"] == prev_price:
        comparison = "Price same as previous price"
    elif my_dict[sorted_lst[i]]["Price"] > prev_price:
        comparison = "Price higher than the previous price"
    elif my_dict[sorted_lst[i]]["Price"] < prev_price:
        comparison = "Price lower than the previous price"
    result_string += "Comparison: \t{}\n".format(comparison)
    print(result_string)
    print("----------------------------------------------")
    prev_date = sorted_lst[i]
    prev_price = my_dict[sorted_lst[i]]["Price"]
    i += 1
```